# How do I construct an 'if' statement to test if the user has paid (paypal merchant tools)?

Tags: paypal

I am setting up a website for people to schedule appointments for $30. I have a form on my website that gathers the buyer's email and the appointment time and date, and I want to use paypal merchant tools to conduct the payment.

I want to store the user's form information in a mySQL database, but I don't want to do this unless the user pays the $30 appointment fee. I already have the code to store the form data in the database, I just need an if statement (in php or javascript) to test whether or not the user has paid the $30 fee when they submit the form.

Again, I'm using paypal merchant tools here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it is best to store the information in a record that is marked as unpaid, and give the user the opportunity to make the payment and then flag it as paid.

So your question is more about how to process a PayPal payment and mark a payment as received in an order record. Well, how are you processing PayPal payments? "Using paypal merchant tools here" is an extraordinarily vague statement. The best way would be to use a variant of the newest PayPal Checkout.  Here is the simplest variant: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The code I am using now is a customized variant of PayPal's "client integration" button that you provided the link to. What code can I use in order to test if the user has paid, thus allowing me to mark the payment as recieved?

Comment: If you need to validate payment on your server, the most straightforward way is to switch to an API-based server-side integration: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server ; then, you have an immediate API response on the server when the payment is captured.

Comment: If you really wanted to, you could implement an asynchronous webhook notification service instead: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/ , but that is in some ways a rather silly idea; why add more side communication dependencies and moving parts. A server-side integration directly offers the capability you need.

Comment: If you're feeling particularly frankensteiny, you can even try keeping the createOrder portion client-side, and only capture on the server. I haven't tested this myself. It probably works out, although no one really recommends it. But it can be an intermediate dev state, and then build out the create order route on your server next.